# How do i use getQsTile outside of the service

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-7.0-nougat

Im trying to access my tile outside of my service but it just returns null. I need to change the state?

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using eventbus. It was really simple

Comment: could you please provide more details here? I am also facing similar problem.

Comment: I think I used eventbus because I could set up the listener anywhere.